# Why does this prompt appear when calculating the range of function values?

Tags: functions

```
FunctionRange[Cos[Abs[x]] - 2 Abs[Sin[x]], x, y] // FullSimplify
```

Why is there such a prompt when using the above code to calculate the value range of a function?

**FunctionRange::eopt: Unable to find the exact range. Returning bounds on the range computed using optimization methods.**

and get the result:

```
-Sqrt[5] <= y <= 1
```

[image]

The result obtained by the software is correct based on the calculation process in the above image, and the function is symmetric about the line x=pi,And the period of the function is 2pi. Why would prompt content still appear?

[image]

To eldo:

```
FunctionRange[Sin[RealAbs[x]] + RealAbs[Sin[x]], x, y]
```

When using RealAbs to calculate the value range of the above functions, the prompt still exists. What is the reason?

[image]

Comment: In the 2nd case `RealAbs` returns `0. <= y <= 2.` and `Abs` returns `1.59995*10^-11 <= y <= 2.`. I don't know why this small difference exists. I also don't know why `RealAbs` handles the first case silently, but issues a warning in the 2nd case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RealAbs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealAbs.html) gives the result without warning (see documentation details)

```
FunctionRange[Cos[RealAbs[x]] - 2 RealAbs[Sin[x]], x, y] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

Comment: Why does using Abs have no effect on function graphs?

Comment: @csn899 Plotting is an inherently numerical process. Once you plug in real numbers, there is no discernible difference between Abs and RealAbs.